# Зависает git push

Tags: git, github, git-push

Здравствуйте, не могу добавить проект в только что созданный репозиторий на github, зависает git push, после Total ждал около 45 мин, висит намертво. Стоит Drweb SS в исключения все добавил, отключение drweb и фаерволла windows не помогают. Система Windows 10. Один раз ошибка вылазила "error: RPC failed; curl 56 OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 10054". Я так понимаю что-то с ssl протоколом. В общем может кто-сталкивался с чем подобным?

```
 $ git push -u origin master
    Counting objects: 21, done.
    Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
    Compressing objects: 100% (20/20), done.
    Writing objects: 100% (21/21), 973.35 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
    Total 21 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
```

Comment: Как много времени проходит от момента запуска команды до момента "зависания"? Если это секунд 10-20, то вполне может быть виноват гейт, который рвёт "неактивные" сессии.

Comment: Конкретную ошибку openssl гуглите сами, может что-то интересное найдётся.

Comment: С момента запуска секунд 4-7 проходит до Total и дальше висит. Про ошибку уже гуглил, на gitlab схожую тему видел, там человеку только установка ubunt'ы помогла(

Comment: Включите KeepAlive в конфигурации и проверьте.

Comment: В общем проблема решилась сама собой, push просто заработал несколько дней спустя)

Answer (score 0):

Была похожая проблема, мне помогло
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906161/git-push-hangs-when-pushing-to-github

```
git config --global core.askpass "git-gui--askpass"
```